# Cross Browser Issues: Web Audio API and Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, eventhandler, web-audio-api

I made a music sequencer that records using web audio. I've got a lot of click events in my javascript, such as:

```
function pause() {
  event.preventDefault();
  clearInterval(playing);
  document.getElementById("pause").classList.add('isActiveCtr');
  document.getElementById("start").classList.remove('isActiveCtr');
}
```

"pause" and "start" are buttons, 'isActiveCtr' is a button color change in css. Everything works in chrome, the sound does not play, but click event changes work in IE and nothing works in safari.

How would I change the event listeners to work across browsers?

Comment: Assuming you use a recent version of Chrome/Safari/IE there is nothing obviously wrong in the code snippet you posted. The problem that causes the sound not to play and event handlers not working might be somewhere else in your code. Could you post more details or exceptions you see?

Comment: Likely unrelated to the problem, but you should use the event *argument* instead of the *global* event variable, like `function pause(event) { ... }`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: Sure, the full code is here: https://github.com/youzelle/afrobeat_sequencer/blob/gh-pages/js/javascript.js